# Odoo 11 25MB limit exceeded

Tags: python, odoo-11

When uploading a new theme `Odoo` 11 says the file, which is 30MB, is larger than 25MB. I changed `odoo/odoo-server/addons/website_slides/controllers/main.py` and restarted `Odoo server` but still get the error. What do I need to change to increase the 25MB upload limit? Keep in mind this is for admin users, not site users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the file upload limit at this line:

[https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/web/static/src/js/fields/basic_fields.js#L1109](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/ef0f9556f8d29502bb4794e44aec01b86e290047/addons/web/static/src/js/fields/basic_fields.js#L1109)

change the code:

```
this.max_upload_size = 25 * 1024 * 1024; // 25Mo
```

To any value you need.

Comment: In addition to this @CT Data Guy, you might also want to consider the limit that your webserver may have, Like nginx and apache, they also apply limits to file sizes